# Load Balanced Server SqlCacheDependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqldependency

I have in-process cache in my web solution.

I have 2 web servers and 1 db.

I have looked at out-of-process caching solutions, but was wondering if I could just setup an SqlCacheDependency instead.

I notice a bug where data is pulled from the cache, the user edits the data, then closes the browser.  If they reopen the browser and come in thru the other webserver it still shows the stale data.

I am using EntityFramework 4.0 Object Context for my data tier.